# All-Pass Filter that increases phase as frequency increases?

Tags: filter

All the all-pass filters I've seen (both lead and lag versions) start at some phase and then lower the phase at some frequency. I need it to increase the phase instead, so instead of having a negative phase slope I'd have a positive one. I can't find a way of increasing phase starting at some frequency without also changing the magnitude. For example, a series 1k resistor with a 10uH inductor to ground will result in phase of 0 at DC, phase of +45 at 16 Hz, and phase of +90 at high frequencies. But it wreaks havoc on the magnitude.

Ultimately I'm looking for a circuit that maintains a flat magnitude profile while creating a phase bump in the desired frequency range (around 10 kHz). The closest thing I've found is a topology similar to a non-inverting amplifier, but with a capacitor in series with the bottom resistor. This produces a phase bump (good) but also boosts the amplitude (bad). The circuit can be found [here](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/control_1/control3.htm), in the lead compensation section.

Comment: With the low frequencies that you are dealing with, you might consider using a microcontroller with an ADC and a DAC.  This solution also ensures that you can adjust your filtering later.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: The component values I listed were just an example, I'd actually be working at a higher frequency. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @slightlynybbled ...OK, that's the hardware, but what's the filter algorithm?

Comment: In the first sentence you speak of an "all-pass filter" (which, of course, can exhibit a rising phase in a certain region) and in the last sentence you mention "lead compensation". Both are different! What do you need? A second-order allpass (classical design) can produce a "phase bump" at any frequency you want.

Comment: Sorry - but I have to correct the last sentence from above. I have mixed-up phase response and group delay. The group delay response (over frequency) can have such a peak - but not the phase response of a 2nd-order allpass.

Comment: @LvW: You claim that an all-pass filter can "exhibit a rising phase in  a certain region". Can you provide an example (including component values) of this? Every filter I've tried that has a rising phase has had a non-flat magnitude.

Comment: I should clarify: I'm looking for the phase to _only_ rise (to some value), without falling. Just like traditional all-pass filters cause the phase to only fall (to some value), without ever rising.

Comment: SharpHawk, didn`t you see my correction? For the moment, I have confused phase and phase slope (group delay). Regarding your wish to have a rising phase: What about the amplitude?

Comment: The amplitude must remain constant (this is why I specified an all-pass filter). In other words, I'm looking for [this](http://web.uvic.ca/~cjam/ELEC484/Assignment%203/Part%207/allpass.bmp) but with the phase rolling up instead of down. Ignore the third graph, since I don't care about group delay.

Comment: I don't think you can design a circuit with a positive phase slope, because that would mean a negative group delay. A negative group delay means the signal must arrive at the circuit's output before it is applied to the input.

Comment: You can have a positive phase slope (see the link in my question), but I don't know if you can also have a flat magnitude while doing so.

Comment: You may be right, I am not sure, but I suspect the combination of the positive phase slope and the peaking in the magnitude response indicates a pole in the right hand plane. If you can tweak a component value and cause a sharp peak in the magnitude response, it probably means the circuit is trying to oscillate.

Comment: @SharpHawk I did some experimenting with a Chebyshev low pass filter by intentionally moving the poles toward the right hand plane. As I suspected, the group delay went negative (positive phase slope) as soon as the poles crossed the imaginary axis int the RHP. I don't think you can design a stable circuit with a positive phase slope.